# How many people share 1 Mbps of an ISP backbone?

Tags: internet, isp, speed

We all know that all consumer based internet connections are shared and that ISPs protect themselves with "best effort" contracts, also we know that a client's 50 Mbps (for example) connection speed is being used by someone else when they are not using it.

But what I am curious about and I believe others are as well, is **how many people actually share that 1 Mbps of an ISP's backbone** or their total throughput.

I am sure that different ISP's have different "ratios", but there must be a general rule or something.

*This seems to be the most relevant site to ask this kind of question, If I'm mistaken mods, I am sorry.*

Comment: This is something only the ISPs can answer, and, I believe, the answers will vary widely, depending on the ISP. I don't think this question can be properly answered here.

Comment: I agree with @RonMaupin; there's no standard for planning and deployment of ISP networks that is enforced by any agency. I have to imagine this depends on wild guesses around high traffic periods and expected utilization. Maybe someone here is an engineer at an ISP and can give an idea without giving away trade secrets. It'd be interesting to see an answer though.

Comment: I'm doing consultancy for many ISPs and this really depends. I have seen everything from 1:4 on premium business connections to 1:100 on low budget subscriptions. And "just keep connecting customers until the line gets too full, then upgrade" is common amongst smaller ISPs as well.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. Your question is asking for what ultimately amounts to opinions (based on the ISP business model) and we are unable to provide a *correct* answer. Please edit your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question.

Comment: To be fair, it's not necessarily immediately obvious that this is opinion based. There are formal standards and informal common practices all over the place in the networks we all run... so it wouldn't be shocking to find similar here. Not saying I disagree (nor agree) with putting the topic on hold, but it's not immediately silly.